# The order of Pauli matrices

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, conventions, lie-algebra

Is there any special reason why Pauli matrices are:
$\sigma _1=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$, $\sigma _2=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & -i \\
 i & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$, $\sigma _3=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$
and not for example 
$\sigma _1=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & -i \\
 i & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$, $\sigma _2=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$, $\sigma _3=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ ?
Will the reason be applicable to Gell-Mann matrices ?

Comment: The two sets do not share the same structure constants. Can you flip signs so they would?

Comment: Which one is done first, fixing the structure constant, or defining the order/index of the matrices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the convention that $1 \leftrightarrow x, 2 \leftrightarrow y, 3 \leftrightarrow z$, the ordering we have ties to the actions performed about $x, y, z$ axes.

- In the context of Pauli's work, $σ_k$ represents the observable corresponding to spin along the $k^{\text{th}}$ coordinate axis in three-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$.
- Also, the Bloch sphere rotations follow that $\exp(i\sigma_{k}\theta)$ rotates the sphere by $\theta/2$ about $k^{\text{th}}$ axis.

Again it is purely conventional, we might have reordered the axes themselves. What you should be wary of though, are the signs as you flip the ordering. Many [algebraic properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Commutation_relations) including commutation relationships, relations to dot and cross products, structure constants in $SU(2)$ and so on may no longer hold and it is better not to change that since many QM and QFT identities look nicer under the normal convention.

> Will the reason be applicable to [Gell-Mann matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices) ?

Same as above. There is no new physics with reordering, it is a convenient choice.

Though it may seem arbitrary to name the only two diagonal matrices as $\lambda_3$ and $\lambda_8$, notice some nice properties. For example,

- $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ are just $2 \times 2$ Pauli matrices embedded in $3$ dimensions.
- There are three independent $SU(2)$ subalgebras whose Casimirs mutually commute:

  1. $\{\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3\}$
  2. $\{\lambda_4, \lambda_5, x\}$
  3. $\{\lambda_6, \lambda_7, y\}$
     where the $x$ and $y$ are linear combinations of $\lambda_3$ and $\lambda_8$.

This is not to say there are no other orderings yielding similar easy-to-remember niceties, but we happen to use this one more.

Answer (score 1):

Your first set of $\sigma_a$ satisfies the standard angular momentum algebra,
$$[\sigma_a, \sigma_b] = 2 i \varepsilon_{a b c}\,\sigma_c .$$

Your second set (name it differently!!), $\Sigma_a: ~~ \{\Sigma_1=\sigma_2, \Sigma_2=\sigma_1,  \Sigma_3=\sigma_3\}$, satisfies an algebra with the opposite structure constants,
$$[\Sigma_a, \Sigma_b] = -2 i \varepsilon_{a b c}\,\Sigma_c .$$

To get an alternate representation of your exact first algebra, you need $s_a\equiv -\Sigma_a$,
$$[s_a, s_b] = 2 i \varepsilon_{a b c}\,s_c .$$

This amounts to a succession of two rotations (around *z* by π/2 and around *x* by π) of your axes from a 
right-handed coordinate system to a likewise right-handed one;  hence a similarity transformation, equivalent to a basis change, *preserving* the original Lie algebra,
$$s_a= (-i\sigma_3) \sigma_a (i\sigma_3)    .$$